# How to use JGit with Maven

Tags: maven, jgit

I'm new to GIT and want to use JGit to create repository and remove it beside other operations from a Java maven project. And I want to know what dependencies are needed for that.

The following link what I read a bout JGit  http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#Getting_Started

Comment: The question is what you want to achieve?

Comment: Don't know if this helps: http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html

Answer (score 1):

You can consume JGit (see http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/download/ ) in Maven:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jgit-repository</id>
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <!-- Core Library -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.201106090707-r</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: i tried it but found that "http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven" from the repository not found. that means it doesn't work

Comment: I tried it again with a clean new project and this worked for me.

Comment: I am not finding anything with the repository url either.

Comment: Rob Williams writes in http://java.dzone.com/articles/embedding-jgit-first-look that he found JGit in the jboss public repo. But for me, the original link worked.

Comment: it is already on [maven central](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/) so `<repositories>` is not necessary any more

Answer (score 0):

It's now in Maven Central, see here

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency in your maven project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0.201705170830-rc1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can choose a later version from the URL below : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit

Answer (score -4):

If you correctly configure git in your Maven Project you can do many things with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/)

Comment: what do u mean with correctly configure git, i searched for jgit dependencies but didn't find any thing on maven repo.